# How to get facebook page fans country location info via API without access token?

Tags: php, database, facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics

I would like to know if it is possible to get facebook page fans country location info   not being the admin of mentioned page as SocialBakers do.

With Facebook Graph it is easy to get total fans but I can't find the way to get local fans without an access token.

In february they published this news about it:

http://www.socialbakers.com/blog/1191-new-local-facebook-page-fan-counts-now-on-socialbakers

I don't know if it is possible to get city location instead of country. I only wan't to pull out the number of fans from each location, not names or any other related info.

It must be through an API to get more than one page insights at the time and add to my database.

Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: The access token is there for a reason. What are you doing with this info? And remember, SocialBakers does because FB sells info, hence the access tokens.

Comment: Ok, with access token is also a possibility. I know how to check the fans by a country but would be perfect If I can do the same with the city location.

Comment: Your talking about taking proprietary information from FB that they directly use for advertising profits. They aren't gonna let it up easily without a token. Its on the verge of inadvertently stealing data from them that they plan on selling.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with an access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/insights
- you shall use GET page-id/insights/page_fans_city